# Can you prove this recursive multiple $n$-sided dice throwing statement?

Tags: probability, number-theory, recursion

Let $W_{s,r,n}$ be the total number of ways that the sum $s$ can be displayed after throwing $r$ number of $n$-sided dice. Define

$$W_{s,0,n} =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if s = 0} \\
0, & \text{if s $\neq$ 0} \\
\end{cases}
$$

for all $s \in \mathbb Z$ and $n \in \mathbb N^*$. Can you prove that

$$W_{s,r,n} =W_{s-1,r,n} + W_{s-1,r-1,n} - W_{s-(1+n),r-1,n}$$

for all $s \in \mathbb Z$, $r \in \mathbb N^*$, and $n \in \mathbb N^*$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You regard the dice as distinguishable, so for example $1+5+6+6$ is distinct from $6+5+1+6$.  So $\displaystyle W_{s,r,n} = \sum_{j=1}^n W_{s-j,r-1,n}$.

There is a proof by induction:

**Base case**: for $r=1$ the recurrence is satisfied by $$W_{s,1,n} =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{ if } 1 \le s \le n \\
0,  & \text{ if } s \le 0 \text{ or } s \ge n+1 \\
\end{cases}$$

**Inductive case**: if it is true for up to $r-1$ dice then

$$W_{s,r,n} = \sum_{j=1}^n W_{s-j,r-1,n} = \sum_{j=1}^n \left(W_{s-j-1,r-1,n} + W_{s-j-1,r-2,n} -  W_{s-j-(1+n),r-2,n}\right)$$ $$= \sum_{j=1}^n W_{s-j-1,r-1,n} + \sum_{j=1}^n W_{s-j-1,r-2,n} - \sum_{j=1}^n W_{s-j-(1+n),r-2,n} $$ $$= W_{s-1,r,n} + W_{s-1,r-1,n} - W_{s-(1+n),r-1,n}$$

so it is true for up to $r$ dice, and so for any positive number of dice.